# Calling findViewById in fragment returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to change TextView in my fragment layout, however I'm getting null value when calling findViewById no matter what.
Here's my fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kubacm.myweather.ShowMeWeather">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Calling fragment from main activity:

```
@Override public void showWeather(JSONObject data){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data",data.toString());
        ShowMeWeather wf = new ShowMeWeather();
        wf.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main,wf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

and in fragment:

```
public class ShowMeWeather extends Fragment {
    Typeface weatherFont;
    TextView cityField;

 public ShowMeWeather() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_me_weather, container, false);
        cityField = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.city_field);
        return rootView;
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        weatherFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/weather.ttf");

        renderWeather();
    }

    public void renderWeather(){
        try{
            cityField.setText("Here should go my text");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Simple Weather","there was an errror");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding my project in Android Studio and still keep getting NullPointerException when I try cityField.SetText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check fragment lifecycle here [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)
Call your renderWeather method after `onCreateView` is completed

Answer (score 1):

`onCreateView` method is called after `onCreate` method, so `cityField` is not yet initialized